# How can I validate dynamic tab and new line delimited string using regex?

Tags: regex, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm trying to implement a validation form with regex where I have to check whether a string is properly `Tab` and `New Line` delimited or not. I'm using [jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/). Column numbers can vary from 2 to 10. Like this image below:
[image]

What regex should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+[\t\n])+[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work:

```
var s = "string here";
var regex = /\t/g;
var lines = s.split(/\n/).length - 1;
var valid = s.match(regex).length == 2 * lines;// valid or not.
alert(valid); // true or false.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VP6Uj/2

Comment: How can I use this with jqBootstrapValidation?